# how to iterate through a 3d array and calculating the mean of each cell

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, dataframe, mean

i want to create a loop for the following lines in python (i use pycharm):

`mean_diff = np.mean(np.array([diff_list[0].values, diff_list[1].values,  diff_list[2].values, diff_list[3].values,...,diff_list[100], axis=0)`

with this i get the mean of each individual cell from different arrays (raster change over time)

i tried the following:

```
for x in range(100):
    mean_diff = np.mean(np.array([diff_list[x].values]), axis=0)
```

but what's happening here is that it will start to calculate the mean between the mean of the last iteration and the new array and so on, instead of adding everything up first and afterwards calculating the mean of the total. one idea was to create a "sumarray" first with all the diff_list values in it, but i failed to do that too. the original type of my diff_list is a list which contains data frames in it (for each row it has an array, so it's a 3d array/data frame (??)... -> see picture: [image shows the structure of the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lBeZ.png)).

Comment: Whats the exact shape of the list? So I can try things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to populate the array, not do the computation, within the loop.  Python list comprehensions are perfect for this:

Your first program is the equivalent of:

```
mean_diff = np.mean(np.array([a.values for a in diff_list[:101]], axis=0))
```

Or if you prefer:

```
x = []
for a in diff_list[:101]:
    x.append(a.values)
mean_diff = np.mean(np.array(x, axis=0))
```

If you are using the whole list instead of its first 101 elements you can drop the "[:101]".

Comment: thanks a lot,this worked!
        only minor comment: the `, axis=0` has to be written outside the brackets - like this: `np.mean(np.array(x), axis=0)`

Comment: My apologies - you're right about the axis=0 thing.